# Как сделать массовый редирект (правило) в htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Есть страницы с такими старыми URL`ами.
site.com/shop/product/name_product

Сейчас структура выглядит так
site.com/name_product

Как перенаправить 301 редиректом страницы?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
# если запрос начинается с /shop/product/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/product/(.+)$  [NC]
# то переадресация с удалением /shop/product/
RewriteRule ^ http://site.com/%1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```